# Change default_country with ajax as guest?

Tags: expresso-store

i want to find a solution to change the default_country of the store for guest members on the checkout page with ajax. I did an ajax submit to update the choosen country but in guest mode this happened only ones and i didn't know why. When i'm logged in as store member it work like it should.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default country in the Store control panel.

Under Store > Settings > Countries / States, simply add a default country and region/state. After you change it, make sure you are logged out and clear your cart, then add an item to your cart and it should pre-select the default country for you automatically.